# How access private methods in abstract class using reflection in Java?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a sample abstract class code as bellow

```
public abstract class AbstractClassA {

    public abstract void m();

    private int aaa(Integer x){

      System.out.println(x);
      return x;  

    }

}
```

Then I try to access this private method as bellow.

```
 Method m = AbstractClassA.class.getDeclaredMethod("aaa", Integer.class);
    m.setAccessible(true);
    m.invoke(5);
```

At that time I'm getting bellow error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

This is not a actual implementation. This is some sample and my actual code abstract class has public method and it is calling the private method.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call to `Method.invoke()` is missing a parameter: The first parameter to it is supposed to be the object the method is to be invoked on; all following parameters are the actual parameters the method is is called with.

Comment: `m.invoke(this, 5);` Replace `this` with the actual instance of AbstractClassA if necessary.

Comment: @Stefan Walter Then we have to create object of abstract class and we have to pass it. Without doing this is there any way to do this?

Comment: @user3496599 The method you wrote about is an *instance* method. You cannot call an instance method without having an instance.

Comment: @user3496599 Addition: If you change the private method to be declared as `static`, you can set the `Method.invoke()`'s parameter to `null`, as described in its API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this library](https://github.com/apperian/JavaAccessor) to generically invoke any public, private, or protected method in Java or Android

Comment: Use this library --> which library